# What is the advantage of Adding a class file in the App_Code folder?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ado.net

In the App_Code folder there are Citymanager and Citymembers. What are the advantages of adding that when creating a user login form?

Is this a good practice?

--below are CRUD for adding cities

```
public Citymanager()
{
}

public int Add(CityMembers CM)
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_cityid_getdata", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city_name", CM.city_name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryid", CM.countryid);
        con.Open();     

        return int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        con.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

public bool Update()
{
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public bool Delete()
{
    try
    {
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It protects the class files from being shown by mistakes on web server configuration, like directory browsing.

Also in my experience, visual studio would never know the class you created unless you place them under App_Code.

[image]

Comment: Not entirely complete answer. You need to be careful. By default IIS Hide/Disable browsing to this folder but this is an IIS configuration which can be changed or removed. You could create your own folder and specify manually that folder to be ignored in the application settings on IIS. same goes for Bin folder if you have it.